# Different versions of `sync` tool

Tags: filesystem, sync, coreutils

There are two `man` pages about the `sync` tool:

(1) http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sync.1.html

```
NAME         

       sync - Synchronize cached writes to persistent storage

SYNOPSIS         top

       sync [OPTION] [FILE]...

DESCRIPTION         top

       Synchronize cached writes to persistent storage

       If one or more files are specified, sync only them, or their
       containing file systems.

       -d, --data
              sync only file data, no unneeded metadata

       -f, --file-system
              sync the file systems that contain the files

       --help display this help and exit

       --version
              output version information and exit
```

(2) http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man8/sync.8.html

```
NAME
       sync - synchronize data on disk with memory

SYNOPSIS
       sync [--help] [--version]

DESCRIPTION
       sync  writes any data buffered in memory out to disk.  This can include
       (but is not limited to)  modified  superblocks,  modified  inodes,  and
       delayed  reads and writes.  This must be implemented by the kernel; The
       sync program does nothing but exercise the sync(2) system call.

       The kernel keeps data in memory to avoid doing (relatively  slow)  disk
       reads  and  writes.   This  improves  performance,  but if the computer
       crashes, data may be lost or the  filesystem  corrupted  as  a  result.
       sync ensures that everything in memory is written to disk.

       sync  should  be  called  before  the processor is halted in an unusual
       manner (e.g., before causing a kernel panic when debugging  new  kernel
       code).    In   general,  the  processor  should  be  halted  using  the
       shutdown(8) or reboot(8) or halt(8) commands, which will attempt to put
       the  system  in  a  quiescent  state  before calling sync(2).  (Various
       implementations of these commands exist; consult your documentation; on
       some systems one should not call reboot(8) and halt(8) directly.)
```

The first one is from `coreutils` while the second is from `fileutils`.
I tried to compile the `sync` tool from `coreutils 8.29` in Ubuntu 14.04 but got the same `sync` as (2).

How do I get the `sync` tool with the functionality (1) on Ubuntu 14.04?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sync` in Ubuntu is from `coreutils`. Check [the package from which it comes](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=sync&mode=exactfilename&suite=trusty&arch=any%20And%20where%20did%20you). The `sync` described in `sync(8)` is an antique that probably never was available on Ubuntu as part of `fileutils`:

```
This page describes sync as found in the fileutils-4.0  package;  other
versions may differ slightly.
```

([`fileutils-4.0` is from 1998.](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/fileutils/))

The `sync(1)` manpage for is what you should be looking at: [14.04](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/sync.1.html), [18.04](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/sync.1.html). Note how 18.04's manpage is just like the man7.org manpage.

If you compiled `sync` from coreutils 8.29 and didn't get those options, you did something wrong, since on Ubuntu 16.04, with the default `sync` from coreutils 8.25, I do get those options:

```
~ sync --help
Usage: sync [OPTION] [FILE]...
Synchronize cached writes to persistent storage

If one or more files are specified, sync only them,
or their containing file systems.

  -d, --data             sync only file data, no unneeded metadata
  -f, --file-system      sync the file systems that contain the files
      --help     display this help and exit
      --version  output version information and exit

GNU coreutils online help: <http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/>
Full documentation at: <http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/sync>
or available locally via: info '(coreutils) sync invocation'
~ sync --version
sync (GNU coreutils) 8.25
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Jim Meyering and Giuseppe Scrivano.
```